# Combining results from two SQL statements into one showing a new result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the below two SQL statements (using SQL Server 2014)

```
SELECT 
    EMP_CLASS_1
    ,SUM(TOT_MI/60) AS [Absent hours]
FROM [TestData].[dbo].[Absenteeism and SLWP TCS Data]
WHERE CODE = 'MLSKU' OR CODE = 'UNPDAB' OR CODE = 'UNPADH'
GROUP BY EMP_CLASS_1
ORDER BY EMP_CLASS_1
```

and the second

```
SELECT 
    EMP_CLASS_1
    ,SUM(TOT_MI/60) AS [Schedule Hours]
FROM [TestData].[dbo].[Absenteeism and SLWP TCS Data]
WHERE code = 'attend'
GROUP BY EMP_CLASS_1
ORDER BY EMP_CLASS_1
```

What I am trying to do is take the results from the first statement and divide it by the results of the second statement.

So far I am not getting any luck.

I am very green at this so please be patient with me.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

As a second question if possible I will like to show all three results at once in three separate columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have corresponding rows between both queries you can use `JOIN`:

```
WITH cte1 AS 
(
  SELECT EMP_CLASS_1
  ,SUM(TOT_MI/60) AS [Absent hours]
  FROM [TestData].[dbo].[Absenteeism and SLWP TCS Data]
  WHERE CODE IN('MLSKU' ,'UNPDAB' , 'UNPADH')
  GROUP BY EMP_CLASS_1
), cte2 AS
(
  SELECT EMP_CLASS_1
    ,SUM(TOT_MI/60) AS [Schedule Hours]
  FROM [TestData].[dbo].[Absenteeism and SLWP TCS Data]
  WHERE code = 'attend'
  GROUP BY EMP_CLASS_1
)
SELECT c1.EMP_CLASS_1
      ,c1.[Absent hours]
      ,c2.[Schedule Hours]
      ,[result] = c1.[Absent hours] / c2.[Schedule Hours]
FROM cte1 c1
JOIN cte2 c2
  ON c1.EMP_CLASS_1 = EMP_CLASS_1
```

or even simpler:

```
SELECT EMP_CLASS_1
   ,SUM(IIF(CODE IN('MLSKU' ,'UNPDAB' , 'UNPADH'), TOT_MI, 0)  /60) AS [Absent hours]
   ,SUM(IIF(CODE ='attend', TOT_MI, 0) /60) AS [Schedule Hours]
   ,SUM(IIF(CODE IN('MLSKU' ,'UNPDAB' , 'UNPADH'), TOT_MI, 0)  /60) 
    / SUM(IIF(CODE ='attend', TOT_MI, 0) /60) AS [result]
FROM [TestData].[dbo].[Absenteeism and SLWP TCS Data]
WHERE CODE IN ('MLSKU' ,'UNPDAB' , 'UNPADH','attend')
GROUP BY EMP_CLASS_1
ORDER BY EMP_CLASS_1;
```

Comment: Thanks lad2025 - still trying to learn SQL.  I really appreciate you taking the time assist me.

Comment: @rasmac Will I get the answer or not?

Comment: Sorry  lad2025  - I did accept your answer not sure why it didn't register.  Once again your help was most appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since you're querying the same table and grouping by the same column, you could achieve this by joining the `where` clauses so that they include both sets of relevant rows and apply the `sum`s on `case` statements with the original conditions.

Note, BTW, that the first query's `where` clause could be written more elegantly using the `in` operator:

```
SELECT   emp_class_1, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN code IN ('MLSKU', 'UNPDAB', 'UNPADH') THEN tot_mi/60 END) /
         SUM(CASE code WHEN 'attend' THEN tot_mi/60 END)
FROM     [TestData].[dbo].[Absenteeism and SLWP TCS Data]
WHERE    code IN ('MLSKU', 'UNPDAB', 'UNPADH', 'attend') 
GROUP BY emp_class_1
ORDER BY emp_class_1
```